# How to set API returned value to Dropdown in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest, dropdown

I am calling API and which returns list of data in JSON and I'm binding that to dropdown as below.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.displayTitle as item.displayTitle for item in JobCtrl.rateType track by item.masterId" ng-model="JobCtrl.jobData.rateType">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Rate Type</option>
</select>
```

We have

```
Hourly,
Monthly,
Quarterly,
Yearly
```

as populated data to this dropdown.

Now when I save the data, say, Yearly as value, Now while editing this page, I'm getting Yearly as data from API, but how I can show Yearly as selected value?

Comment: whats the response from API , just show us the response format please or create fiddle

Comment: can you paste one object from "JobCtrl.rateType" in your question please